# SQLite header and source version mismatch

Tags: software-installation, sqlite

I had the Ubuntu repositories of SQLite3 with `v3.7.17`. But it doesn't have the `.save` command as newer versions.

To update I did:

1. `sudo apt-get purge sqlite3`
2. Download [SQLite 3.8.4.3](https://www.sqlite.org/2014/sqlite-autoconf-3080403.tar.gz)
3. Install it with `./configure && make && sudo make install`

But now when I try to run `sqlite3` from command line I get:

```
SQLite header and source version mismatch
2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
2014-04-03 16:53:12 a611fa96c4a848614efe899130359c9f6fb889c3
```

Searching I found two solutions that I've tried without success:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16366457/1505348) didn't work because I don't have `sqlite` on `/usr/bin`
- [This solution](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1143610#p1143610) didn't work neither, but I did backup to revert those useless changes.

Any idea of how to solve this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After building from source, your **v3.8.4.3** version is now installed in `/usr/local/lib`.

You need to replace `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` (or `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` for i386 arch) with the one from `/usr/local/lib`:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just downloaded and compiled it on Debian and had the same problem.  I solved it by statically linking sqlite3 :

```
./configure --disable-dynamic-extensions --enable-static --disable-shared
make
make install
```

You probably only need `--enable-static` but I specifically added `--disable-shared` to be sure.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the sqlite3 binary was being called from a specific user login (batch script). The script was seeing `/usr/bin/sqlite3` before its own application installed sqlite3 version though the libraries of the second were being read and not from the first. I added `${path to special application ~/bin}` to the front of the `export PATH=` line in the users `.bashrc` file.